# Calculating size of vector of vectors in bytes

Tags: c++, sizeof

```
typedef vector<vector<short>> Mshort;
typedef vector<vector<int>> Mint;

Mshort mshort(1 << 20, vector<short>(20, -1)); // Xcode shows 73MB 
Mint mint(1 << 20, vector<int>(20, -1)); // Xcode shows 105MB
```

short uses 2 bytes and int 4 bytes; please note that `1 << 20 = 2^20`;

I am trying to calculate ahead (on paper) usage of memory but I am unable to.

```
sizeof(vector<>) // = 24 //no matter what type
sizeof(int) // = 4
sizeof(short) // = 2
```

I do not understand: `mint` should be double the `mshort` but it isn't. When running program only with `mshort` initialisation **Xcode shows 73MB of memory usage; for `mint` 105MB**;

```
mshort.size() * mshort[0].size() * sizeof(short) * sizeof(vector<short>) // = 1006632960
mint.size() * min[0].size() * sizeof(int) * sizeof(vector<int>) // = 2013265920

//no need to use .capacity() because I fill vectors with -1
1006632960 * 2 = 2013265920
```

How does one calculate how much space of RAM will 2d `std::vector` use or 2d `std::array` use.

I know the sizes ahead and each row has same number of columns.

Comment: I suppose what you're doing is measuring your program's total memory consumption while you intend to measure just the vector part. Once you subtract the runtime overhead it should be roughly twice as much

Comment: Well I run only #include <vector>, typedefs, main(), initialization of either mint or mshort and cout. (and breakpont on return of main where I check memory usage)

Comment: @mewa even if, the calculation I make is wrong, it spits out those large numbers, so I am doing something wrong. From googling around sizeof() should return type_t with bytes usage.

Comment: Also, capacity has to be used, since as you have already noticed sizeof vector is constant and equals its static size. Vector elements are stored in an underlying resizable array (dynamic). If you want to calculate total space requirements you'd have to add vector's sizeof instead of multiplying by it

Comment: @mewa makes sense! I will check tomorrow, its pretty late I hoped that I don't make silly mistake.

Comment: Just remove that sizeof vector multiply line - it should be a ~ 40MB, that leaves ~30MB overhead. When you double those 40MBs you're gonna get a value close to what xcode is showing. If you calculate the the vectors' static size and take it into account the difference should be exactly that

Comment: @mewa it all makes sense now; could you please elaborate on whats exactly "overhead"? (What should I google for) why is 30MB overhead for such simple program that just allocates bunch of memory, will it change if I allocate on heap?

Comment: You can get an idea of the memory used by looking at the address of each vector `&mshort[0]` and `&mshort[1]` ....  Also look at `&mshort[0][0]`

Comment: @Kyslik The overhead comes from included libraries, for example iostream. However judging by the size you may have included libraries you aren't using. Also the simple calculation only gives size for ints or shorts, but vectors wrapping them also take up a couple bytes and since you're allocating quite a few hence the additional memory cost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory usage of your vectors of vectors will be e.g.

```
// the size of the data...
mshort.size() * mshort[0].size() * sizeof(short) +

// the size of the inner vector objects...
mshort.size() * sizeof mshort[0] +

// the size of the outer vector object...
// (this is ostensibly on the stack, given your code)
sizeof mshort +

// dynamic allocation overheads
overheads
```

The dynamic allocation overheads are because the `vector`s internally `new` memory for the elements they're to store, and for speed reasons they may have pools of fixed-sized memory areas waiting for new requests, so if the `vector` effectively does a `new short[20]` - with the data needing 40 bytes - it might end up with e.g. 48 or 64.  The implementation may actually need to use some extra memory to store the array size, though for `short` and `int` there's no need to loop over the elements invoking destructors during `delete[]`, so a good implementation will avoid that allocation and no-op destruction behaviour.

The actual data elements for any given vector are contiguous in memory though, so if you want to reduce the overheads, you can change your code to use fewer, larger `vector`s.  For example, using one `vector` with `(1 << 20) * 20` will have negligible overhead - then rather than accessing `[i][j]` you can access `[i * 20 + j]` - you can write a simple class wrapping the `vector` to do this for you, most simply with a `v(i, j)` notation...

```
inline short& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) { return v_[i * 20 + j]; }
inline short operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const { return v_[i * 20 + j]; }
```

...though you could support `v[i][j]` by having `v.operator[]` return a proxy object that can be further indexed with `[]`.  I'm sure if you search SO for questions on multi-dimension arrays there'll be some examples - think I may have posted such code myself once.

The main reason to want `vector<vector<x>>` is when the inner `vector`s vary in length.

Comment: Yes thats is exactly what I planned to do; use one large vector on heap, I will be allocating 2^26 (or 2^27). Or not use vector at all and stick to array (1d) but large. Thas why I wanted calculation first so I know what can my machine handle...

Comment: @Kyslik.  Hope that goes well.  Posted a little more detail in case it helps....  Cheers.

Comment: and its not (1d vec) vec[i*(isize)+j] but vec[i*(jsize)+j]. In my example its vec[i*(20)+j] and not vec[i*(1 << 20)+j]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming glibc malloc:
Each memory chunk will allocate additional 8-16 bytes(2 size_t) for memory block header. For 64 bit system it would be 16 bytes.
see code:
https://github.com/sploitfun/lsploits/blob/master/glibc/malloc/malloc.c#L1110

```
chunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |             Size of previous chunk, if allocated            | |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |             Size of chunk, in bytes                       |M|P|
  mem-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |             User data starts here...                          .
    .                                                               .
    .             (malloc_usable_size() bytes)                      .
    .                                                               |
```

It gives me approximately 83886080 for short when adding 16 bytes per row.

26+16+ mshort.size(1048576) * (mshort[0].size(20)*sizeof(short(2)) + sizeof(vector(26))+header(16))

It gives me approximately 125829120 for int.

But then I recompute you numbers and it look like you are on 32 bit...

- short 75497472 that is ~73M
- long 117440512 that is ~112M

Looks very close to reported ones.

Use capacity not size to get #items number, even if those are the same in your case.

Allocating single vector size row*columns will save you header*1048576 bytes.

Comment: Hello, I am on 64 bit machine OS X (10.10.5).

Comment: @Kyslik you could compile with 32 bit settings. Anyway above description explains where extra memory comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation `mshort.size() * mshort[0].size() * sizeof(short) * sizeof(vector<short>) // = 1006632960` is simply wrong. As your calculation, `mshort` takes 1006632960 which is 960MiB, which is not true.

Let's ignore libc's overhead, and just focus on `std::vector<>`'s size:
`mshort` is a `vector` of `1^20` items, each is `vector<short>` with 20 items.
So the size shall be:

`mshort.size() * mshort[0].size() * sizeof(short) // Size of all short values
  + mshort.size() * sizeof(vector<short>) // Size of 1^20 vector<short>
  + sizeof(mshort) // Size of mshort itself, which can be ignored as overhead`

The calculated size is **64MiB**.

The same to mint, where the calculated size is **104MiB**.

So `mint` is simply **NOT** double size of `mshort`.